# Android: Parse beforesave to database

Tags: android, parse-platform, before-save

I am going to save records to Parse database.

### Saving to Parse:

```
    ParseObject database = null;
    database = new ParseObject("Record_db");
    database.put("period_ref",  current1_draw_ref_I);
    database.put("remark",          "na");
    database.put("publishing",      "publishing");
    database.saveInBackground();
```

### Cloud Code:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("check_duplicate", function(request, response) 
{
    var DB = Parse.Object.extend("Record_db"); 
    var query = new Parse.Query(DB);
        query.equalTo("period_ref", request.object.get("period_ref"));
        query.first
        ({
      success: function(object) 
    {
            if (object) 
        {
                response.error("A Period with this ref already exists.");
            } 
        else
        {
                response.success();
            }
      },
      error: function(error) 
    {
        response.error("Could not validate uniqueness for this period ref object.");
        }
    });  
});
```

### Question:

The records can be saved to the `Record_db` database. But I do not know how to connect and invoke the "check_duplicate" cloud function for checking duplicate beforeSave. I found there are no tutorials or documentations on such basic operations.

How such beforesave works and when should it be called???

Could you please kindly tell me how to write in the Android code to check duplicate (if duplicate then do not save, if it is new record, then save to Parse DB) and then save to Parse? This basics stuck me for a week which is so desperating...Many thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Not at my PC atm but if no answer is provided by tonight, I will get back to you. Looks like you are pretty close.

Comment: many thanks for your kind help. I am really getting lost and astonished that cannot find documentation for a complete cycle!

Comment: In defense of parse.com, this guide does cover the subjects of modifying objects when saving/deleting https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide

Comment: @pearmak where did you put the Cloud code? how did you link it with android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close with your implementation, however, the `before*`/`after*` methods require the parameter being the actual classname the code should be run for, not a random method name.

`beforeSave`,`afterSave` and `beforeDelete`,`afterDelete`, get invoked automatically by Parse once an object of the class defined in the function definition is saved.

So instead of naming the method `check_duplicate`, use the classname `Record_db` like so:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Record_db", function(request, response) {
    //... your code ...
});
```

Also please note that these methods run on *every* save, not just on object creation, you can use `request.object.isNew()` to check if the object that gets saved is new or already existed.

Comment: thx for your direction and explanation. that means the `beforeSave` is run everytime something is uploaded to the DB, and it will run itself, we no need to fire it to run? and so I just to `database.saveInBackground();` and it will get run itself?

Comment: That's the concept of these methods, yes. Every time you save an object of a class that has a `beforeSave`, it will run.

Comment: This answer covers my intended answer. The 'is-this-already-existing' query should work just fine as I see it.