# how to call Parse.Cloud.beforeSave in android

Tags: android, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have a ParseObject called Book. I create a beforeSave function for it so as to avoid duplicates. How do I call the function from the android client? Or is the function magically called by Parse each time I try to persist a Book object? My book class is

```
ParseClassName("Book")
public class Book extends ParseObject {
...
}
```

So to save a book object, with the `beforeSave` filter, do I simply do

```
Book book = new Book();
...//set fields
book.saveInBackground(...);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this may be of use to you:
[Android: Parse beforesave to database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29060305/android-parse-beforesave-to-database)

"
beforeSave, afterSave and beforeDelete, afterDelete, get invoked automatically by Parse once an object of the class defined in the function definition is saved.
"

Hope it helps.